# Crystal Report File Path

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Is it posible to put crystal report file in some site, like :

```
http://localhost/DocumentRPT/ProductPerTenorByProductID.rpt
```

And then, I executed with

> ReportDocument.load(serverPath)

Or, any suggestion in common publishing  method?

Many thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

there is property of report viewer ReportPath  you can assign it from code behind

```
  ReportViewertrans.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Your path to rpt");
```

or

```
report.Load(Server.MapPath("Report1.rpt"))
```